# Required response answer in Mechanical Turk

Tags: html, algorithm, api, mechanicalturk

I am designing my task in MTurk and have tried to create a field with the required answer.
That is my code:

```
<crowd-input name="Comment" placeholder="Explain why" required></crowd-input>
```

The problem is that submitting the task without filling any text in the sandbox allowed me to do so. I want this text box to be required.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Explain why" required></input>
```